# gcloud promote a version

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

So, I've deployed a custom runtime to gcloud (with --no-promote), using:

```
gcloud preview app deploy --project $PROJECT_NAME --version ${VERSION} --no-promote --quiet app.yaml
```

I saw that it all works well, and now I want to route traffic to it.
Using the UI, it is simple - just checking the version's checkbox, and clicking a button.

However, from the CLI, it appears that I need specify the app.yaml again.
Why is that? Everything was already deployed...

Is there a way to route traffic to it (i.e., "promote" it), without having to specify app.yaml again? i.e., other means rather than:

```
gcloud preview app deploy --project $PROJECT_NAME --version ${VERSION} --promote --quiet app.yaml
```

Thanks for all your help.

Cheers,

Ohad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
gcloud preview app modules set-default <module_name> --version <version_name> --project=<project_name>
```

This will set the specified version as default for the module you want. Additional documentation can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/modules/set-default

Answer (score 1):

My solution in 2022 used in pipeline script:

```
gcloud --project "$PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION" app versions migrate  "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

Documentation link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/migrate